# Is it possible to unmute the line-in/microphone output on a laptop?

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, microphone, audio-output

I want to unmute line-in/microphone sound on a laptop. On my desktop PC, it's disabled by default, so you don't hear sound coming from it at all times, but it can be unmuted via `Control Panel > Sound > Speaker properties > Levels`. This allows me to hear the output from whatever device is connected, be it a microphone, nintendo DS, FM radio etc.

The problem is, that on all 3 of my laptops, the Levels tab has no option to mute anything other than the speakers themselves, so I can't hear anything without first recording it. What's going on?

Answer (score 1):

I think the capability to monitor line-in (i.e. play to a speaker what is coming in to line-in) depends on the specific audio card/chipset and associated drivers.

On my Vista PC, with Realtek sound, I would have to run a recording program such as Audacity and set it's preferences to "play-through" then Audacity appears in my sound-mixer and can be muted or unmuted there.

[image: sound mixer etc]

The Windows sound-recorder doesn't support play-through, you need a third-party application.

As I say, I believe this depends on your Sound Mixer, whose capabilities seem to depend on your specific sound-card drivers.